# How to break up a 2D array of varying sizes using if statements in a loop?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

Say I have the 2D array called `2d = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]` and
`2d` will only ever have row size or 3 or 4.

I want to be able to grab all elements in the list for use like so:

```
for row in 2d:
    if len(row)==3:
        print(1st_val, 2nd_val, 3rd_val)
    if len(row)==4:
        print(1st_val, 2nd_val, 3rd_val, 4th_val)
```

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Carcigenicate already showed one way to unpack all the values.

If, instead, you need something like your original code, `list[n]` is what you use to get individual items:

```
two_d = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]

for row in two_d:
    if len(row)==3:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2])
    if len(row)==4:
        print(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

You can try that in https://repl.it/join/aodrqjib-tonialatalo

Answer (score 2):

To print out `row` regardless of its size, you can use

```
for row in 2d:
    print(*row)
```

That will expand `row` into multiple arguments given to `print`, and will work for any size of `row`.

You can see examples of unpacking [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/).

Answer (score 2):

You have been shown in other answers how to index the array and how to access all elements without indexing.  A further option.  If you want to extract the contents of a list of known length into a fixed number of other variables, then you can unpack it like this:

```
rows = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]

for row in rows:
    if len(row) == 3:
        val1, val2, val3 = row
        print(val1, val2, val3)
    if len(row) == 4:
        val1, val2, val3, val4 = row
        print(val1, val2, val3, val4)
```

although it is often more convenient to keep the values in a list and index it as required.

(On a separate point, the second `if` could be replaced by `elif`.)